# saving Backbone.model via XEditable

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, x-editable

I am using Backbone and using `XEditable` for inline editing.

i am doing the following in the `url` part as one of the parameters to be passed to call for function `editable` of XEditable :

```
url: function(params) {
            console.log(params);
            console.log(here.model);
            var saveUrl = here.model.url;
            here.model.url += '/'+here.model.attributes._id; //setting required url for the request to be sent on the server
                var d = new $.Deferred;
                here.model.save( 
                  {field:params.value},
                  { patch: true }, 
                  { error: function() {
                    console.log("error");
                      d.reject('Server Error..!');
                    }
                  },
                  { success: function() {
                    console.log("done");
                    d.resolve();
                    }
                  }
                );
                return d.promise();
              }
```

But when i save the data on the server

i get the error :

```
POST http://10.0.1.6:3000/g/spec/5229d8fff4ae7a3803000020 404 (Not Found) on console and
```

also : on the browser, the saving state of X editable never ends.. means X editable goes on a infinite loop to print some message.

My first question why data is not able to be saved on the server?
I have correctly checked this url via `POSTMAN` chrome plugin.

2nd Question is : if somehow data is not able to be saved on database, as i am using deferred object and rejecting the promise in case of error, why X-editable is not showing the error "Server Error..!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just leave url empty and use the x-editable success-callback, if you want to use backbone's one model.save. Eg. in the view's render-method, you have to set update your model and trigger save (manually or by change-handler for the model)

```
this.$el.find("#my-field").editable({
    type        : 'text',
    name        : myFieldTitle,
    value       : myCurrentValue,
    pk          : this.model.get('id'),
    url         : '',
    success     : function(response, newValue) {
        self.model.set(field.name, newValue);
        self.model.save(field.name, newValue);
    }
});
```